# Android setLogo isnt placed on the center of Action Bar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Hi I am using a toolbar and trying to set a logo to the center of action bar. But in the center there was title and (I think) thats why logo was starting from the left side of the action bar. Then I removed title to place the logo in center but it did no good. How can I solve this?

Here is the method I use to set the toolbar.

```
 private void setToolBar(){
       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorActionBar));
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logoactionbar);

    }
```

Here is the theme in my manifest

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And here is the decleration of toolbar

```
      <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.anadolusigorta.rhextranet.com.anadolusigorta.rhextranet.HomeActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/statusBarBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorActionBar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logoactionbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you have create a custom toolbar

Comment: you may want to use ReleativeLayout instead of CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: When I do this logo is not shown.When I do this logo is not shown. I am usign coordinator layout, I am updating the xml decleration of app bar

Comment: After changing my xml this worked, I am accepting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/your_logo"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: When I do this logo is not shown. I am usign coordinator layout, I am updating the xml decleration of app bar

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is just a ViewGroup, you can customize that as you want.

Try This:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: This seems like the right approach but doesnt give the right result. The logo is placed to the below